# how to return matrix corner detected using goodFeaturesToTrack

Tags: opencv

How can I write a command to return matrix corner detected using goodFeaturesToTrack?

```
goodFeaturesToTrack(gray_image, corners, maxCorners, 
          qualityLevel, minDistance,temp_image, 2, true, 0.04);

Mat harris;
harris = original_image.clone();

for (unsigned int i=0; i corners.size(); i++)
{
    circle(harris, corners[i], 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0),-1,8,0);
    cout<<"Corners Vector: " << WHAT TO WRITE HERE? << endl;
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear - what you want to find there? isn't it the `corners[i]`?

Comment: basically I want to find the pixel location of the detected corner. Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[goodFeaturesToTrack](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=goodfeaturestotrack#void%20goodFeaturesToTrack%28InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20corners,%20int%20maxCorners,%20double%20qualityLevel,%20double%20minDistance,%20InputArray%20mask,%20int%20blockSize,%20bool%20useHarrisDetector,%20double%20k%29) returns a corner point list of type `vector<Point2f>`. So, to print out the corner points you could do the following:

```
cout << "Corner Point [" << i << "]: " << endl;
cout << "x = " << corners[i].x << endl;
cout << "y = " << corners[i].y << endl;
```

Also, have a look at the [lkdemo.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp), and the [goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/TrackingMotion/goodFeaturesToTrack_Demo.cpp) for more examples of usage.

Comment: Mevatron thank you for the guide. I didn't put .x and .y after corners[i]. May I know how does it locate the detected corners? Is it in sequence like in matlab like the bounding box or it just randomly select and then display?

Comment: It uses either Harris corner detection or Eigen values and vectors to compute the corners. You can control this somewhat with the `qualityLevel` parameter. Here is the wiki for the math behind the Harris corners: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_.26_Stephens_.2F_Plessey_.2F_Shi-Tomasi_corner_detection_algorithm.

Comment: oh.does it mean that the most significant corners are printed out first then followed by the least significant?

Comment: According to the documentation "The remaining corners are sorted by the quality measure in the descending order." So, yes :)